# Why is there always a great circle through two points on the sphere?

Tags: geometry, intuition, spheres

I have the following understanding of this: the plane that contains the two points and the centre of the sphere cuts the sphere into two equal parts. The intersection of the plane and the sphere is the great circle we are looking for.

But I am failing to show why this works.An intuitive proof that I can present to an audience who has no knowledge of calculus would be helpful.

Comment: What you wrote is a proof that can be presented to an audience with no knowledge of calculus, and to one with knowledge of calculus too.

Comment: What is the "why" you are failing to show?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Agreed. But why does this indeed give a great circle?

Comment: You mean `two equal parts`, right?

Comment: Isn't it the case that any plane passing through the centre of a sphere bisects the sphere?

Comment: @user1952500 yes it is. I need to show why.

Comment: What definition of a great circle are you using? I ask because in some treatments the definition of a great circle is precisely the intersection of the sphere with a plane through the center.

Comment: @Agnishom Chattopadhyay When cut by a plane not containing the center you get a "small" circle of intersection.A sting tightened along such line will slip off.

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is a plane (and it is unique if the two points are not antipodal) which passes through the two given distinct points and the center of the sphere. The intersection of this plane and the sphere gives the great circle (each plane cut a the sphere along a circle, if it passes through the center then its radius is the radius of the sphere).

Comment: That is what I pointed out in the question, already. I want an intuitive proof of why this is a great circle

Comment: @Agnishom Chattopadhyay Each plane cut a the sphere along a circle, if it passes through the center then its radius is the radius of the sphere. That is the distance of the center to any boundary point is the radius of the sphere.

Answer (score 2):

Rotate the ball so that both points are on the equator.

If that’s too much to gamble, just rotate so one point is on the equator. Then if you rotate around the axis through that point, the second point will move between northern and southern hemispheres, so by the intermediate value theorem you can move it to the equator as well. (It’s also possible the second point is directly on the other side of the sphere and will remain fixed, in which case it’s already on the equator.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most appropriate way to explain it to any one could be to demonstrate it using a plastic ball (table tennis ball). Give your friend a marker to mark two points on the ball. Then, you can ask them to connect those points along the curvature of the ball (which should be the shortest path between them). Then, ask them that on extending the arc between the points into a full circle. Then cut the ball into two along the circle drawn and measure the radius of each hemisphere formed which must be equal if the circle formed was a great circle.